# mysql_real_escape_string equivalent for Golang

Tags: security, go, escaping

I would like to escape a value that makes up part of a database query, but I can't use parameterized queries.

Does Go have an equivalent of PHP's `mysql_real_escape_string` I can use to escape the query value?

Comment: The entire *query* is passed from the command line? Then I don't understand what exactly you want to escape in the first place?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string won't help you if your entire query is passed from commadline. Try to refactor so it won't be so, and only parameters are passed to your app. If that's not possible, and you want to avoid malicious queries, your best option would be to use an SQL parser and do some static analysis on the input.

Comment: Re your edit: what we said still applies I'm afraid - you either have a single value that you're inserting - then you can use parametrized queries - or you have a full or partial query, then escaping it won't do you any good and you would have to break it down using a SQL parser and filter out anything malicious yourself.

Comment: You've since edited your question (so I can't see the original) but ask about *what* you want to do, not *how*. There may be other ways besides escaping queries and crossing your fingers to achieve what you want. User provided, arbitrary queries sounds a lot like madness otherwise.

Comment: OP can you maybe give an example of how the input passed is used as part of the query and why it can't be parameterized?

Answer (score 9):

I came up with my own solution to create the function myself.
Hope it would be useful to someone.

```
func MysqlRealEscapeString(value string) string {
    replace := map[string]string{"\\":"\\\\", "'":`\'`, "\\0":"\\\\0", "\n":"\\n", "\r":"\\r", `"`:`\"`, "\x1a":"\\Z"}

    for b, a := range replace {
        value = strings.Replace(value, b, a, -1)
    }
    
    return value;
}
```

1.MysqlRealEscapeString is not right, as below test case will fail

```
func TestEscape(t *testing.T) {
    mysqlEscapeList := map[string]string{
        "\\": "\\\\", "'": `\'`, "\\0": "\\\\0", "\n": "\\n", "\r": "\\r", `"`: `\"`, "\x1a": "\\Z"}

    for old, want := range mysqlEscapeList {
        testEscape(t, old, want)
    }
    testEscape(t, `<p>123</p><div><img width="1080" />`, `<p>123</p><div><img width=\"1080\" />`)
}
func testEscape(t *testing.T, origin, want string) {
    escaped := MysqlRealEscapeString(origin)
    assert.Equal(t, want, escaped)
}
```

2. use this one instead

```
func Escape(sql string) string {
    dest := make([]byte, 0, 2*len(sql))
    var escape byte
    for i := 0; i < len(sql); i++ {
        c := sql[i]

        escape = 0

        switch c {
        case 0: /* Must be escaped for 'mysql' */
            escape = '0'
            break
        case '\n': /* Must be escaped for logs */
            escape = 'n'
            break
        case '\r':
            escape = 'r'
            break
        case '\\':
            escape = '\\'
            break
        case '\'':
            escape = '\''
            break
        case '"': /* Better safe than sorry */
            escape = '"'
            break
        case '\032': //十进制26,八进制32,十六进制1a, /* This gives problems on Win32 */
            escape = 'Z'
        }

        if escape != 0 {
            dest = append(dest, '\\', escape)
        } else {
            dest = append(dest, c)
        }
    }

    return string(dest)
}
```

Comment: Note that in Go, map is unordered, so the replaces may happen in any order, But the double backslash has to be applied before any other rule. You might want to use [][2]string for the rules instead.

Answer (score 4):

If the entire *query* - or any part of the query that goes beyond a single value - is passed from the command line, there is nothing for you to escape.

`mysql_real_escape_string` and its cousins are for sanitizing single values, to prevent anyone with access to the value before it is inserted into the query from "breaking out" and fiddling with the query itself.

Given that you are giving access to the entire query to an outside, there is nothing an escape function could do to improve safety.

Your only shot at security here is

- executing the query in a user context that can't do any damage (e.g. you can restrict commands on a per-user basis in mySQL)
- making sure that query errors are properly caught and dealt with
- as Not_a_Golfer suggests in the comments above, parsing the query for anything malicious

Answer (score 2):

Improved answer:

```
func MysqlRealEscapeString(value string) string {
    var sb strings.Builder
    for i := 0; i < len(value); i++ {
        c := value[i]
        switch c {
        case '\\', 0, '\n', '\r', '\'', '"':
            sb.WriteByte('\\')
            sb.WriteByte(c)
        case '\032':
            sb.WriteByte('\\')
            sb.WriteByte('Z')
        default:
            sb.WriteByte(c)
        }
    }
    return sb.String()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use Prepared Queries.

**To Retrieve Multiple Rows**

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("select id, name from users where id = ?")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer stmt.Close()
rows, err := stmt.Query(1)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
    // ...
}
if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

To Retrieve Single Row

```
var name string
err = db.QueryRow("select name from users where id = ?", 1).Scan(&name)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(name)
```